Библиотека telebot завершает скрипт с кодом ошибки 0xC0000135
Пишу бота для Telegram с использованием библиотеки telebot (pyTelegramBotAPI).

Установил Python 3.
Установил эту библиотеку:  pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
На всякий случай обновил Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable

Пишу скрипт, запускаю его - он завершается с таким сообщением: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
Причём это сообщение выдаётся даже если скрипт сократить до одной строчки:
import telebot

В чём может быть причина этой ошибки?
